# Why is my Observer subscriber not running if I call it after I call an async function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, observable, rxjs

I have some code that looks like this:

```
async function promptHandler(source) {
    source.subscribe(function(line) {
      console.log(`line == ${line}`);
    });
    let matchingTests = await getMatchingTests('ROGL');
}
```

This prints out the contents of the `source` Observable, which is listening to a `ReadStream` of a `txt` file. When the function as it is above is called, I see the output of the file. However, if I call `subscribe()` *after* `getMatchingTests()` gets called, like this:

```
async function promptHandler(source) {
    let matchingTests = await getMatchingTests('ROGL');
    source.subscribe(function(line) {
      console.log(`line == ${line}`);
    });
}
```

I don't see the contents of the txt file. I know that the matchingTests variable contains the successful results of `getMatchingTests`, so I don't think it's preventing Node from executing that line.

I'm guessing that something about the `getMatchingTests` async function call is messing with the `source` Observable, but I'm not seeing how.

Here's my `source` code:

```
let fileStream = createReadStream(file)
    .pipe(split());

let source = new Observable(o => {
   fileStream.on('data', line => {console.log('data'); o.next(line);});
   fileStream.on('error', err => o.error(err));
   fileStream.on('end', () => {console.log('end'); o.complete();});
});
```

Comment: Can you publish the code for the observable source? Maybe that could help understand what is going on

Comment: do you see nonetheless `'data'` printed in the console for each line of the file? If you do, and yet you don't see any text like `line ===...` , then definitely your subscribe operation happens too late. Cf. my answer.

Comment: I don't see `'data'` or `line ===...`

Comment: Sorry, of course you don't. The function you pass when you create the observable is only executed when you subscribe. So if you subscribe after all lines have been emitted/read, then there is no more `data` event on your filestream. For the same reason you will not see `end` and `error` either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My intuition here is that the source observable is a hot source, and that by the time `await` has returned with the matching tests, your text file is already read. So when you subscribe at that point, there is no line to read, they were read before you subscribed to the source.

UPDATE :
Given your code, if the ordering is a problem for your use case, you can consider moving the filestream creation into the observable factory, i.e.

```
let source = new Observable(o => {
let fileStream = createReadStream(file)
    .pipe(split());
   fileStream.on('data', line => {console.log('data'); o.next(line);});
   fileStream.on('error', err => o.error(err));
   fileStream.on('end', () => {console.log('end'); o.complete();});
});
```

That way, the stream will be created and started only when you subscribe.